# Does javascript creates a execution context for every function?

Tags: javascript, function, execution

I am watching a course where the professor mentions a local execution context being created every time we execute a function  created by ourselves (he does not says exactly that, however he does not mentions this when he explains external functions like `setTimeOut` or `fetch`). However what happens when we call an external function (like `setTimeOut` or `fetch`) does javascript creates a local execution context for this functions too? What I mean by external functions is functions not created by ourself but part of an API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most external functions for javascript are actually written in C, so they don't have a javascript execution context per se. However, they still have [a stack frame](http://www.cs.uwm.edu/classes/cs315/Bacon/Lecture/HTML/ch10s07.html), which is similar to what a javascript execution context is.

Comment: So for example when I call ```setTimeOut``` this function has nothing to do with javascript but is only an api for triggering a timer in the browser and because is the browser that will execute the timer it's there where the execution context (stack frame) is created?

Comment: Browsers implement the `setTimeout` function, usually in C, which doesn't have javascript's execution contexts.